# How to allow ng-model input html in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean, meanjs

I have html code:

```
<div class="inner-content-linkaudio">
  <label for="linkaudio">Link audio</label>
  <input type="url" name="linkaudio" ng-model="linkaudio" class="form-control">
</div>
```

But when I enter to input, and press button submit form, I have error:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{postcurrent.linkaudio}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL:
```

How do I can allow enter url and submit form without error? Thank you.

Comment: did you properly define the objects in your controller scope?

Comment: Provide a fiddle please,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of [Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce). Angular will refuse to load/render a string value which has not been explicitly trusted as a resource URL by the SCE policy. This is done as a security measure, in order to maintain control what resources can be loaded into your app.

You can write a directive which extends a sibling [`NgModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) to trust all input as a resource URL

```
angular.module('test', [])
  .directive('trustedUrl', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
          return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(value);
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

which can then be used as

```
<input type="url" ng-model="url" trusted-url />
<audio ng-src="{{ url }}" controls></audio>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWmxJwanBk43LSbP2AwS?p=preview) is a working Plunker. You can test by pasting an audio URL into the input.

---

Another option is to use [`$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([...])`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider#resourceUrlWhitelist) to whitelist only some URLs as those which can be loaded into your app.

Comment: Well, it is very good idea, i will apply it, thank you very much, stackoverfow is fantastic community.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your postcurrent variable is defined on the scope

```
$scope.postcurrent={linkaudio:""};
```

Comment: Thank you everybody.I have just found it, I have disabled SCE completely, so it didn't show error. This is code help me: angular.module('myAppWithSceDisabledmyApp', []).config(function($sceProvider) {
  // Completely disable SCE.  For demonstration purposes only!
  // Do not use in new projects.
  $sceProvider.enabled(false);
});

Comment: Anybody have new idea for this problem ? Please suggest me. I really appreciate it